# Conceptual doubts about Zabbix

Tags: php-fpm, zabbix

Conceptual doubts about  ZABBIX

In the context of  “web application monitoring”,  is it possible and recommendable to have Zabbix  working on a server different  from the one that contains tha web-app to be monitored??

If yes, how do I link both servers to work together?

If not, how should I ACCES to zabbix’s control panel via web? … What catches my attention the most is the fact that the default way to acces is by browsing  either www.zabbix.mydomain.com   or www.mydomain.com/zabbix and for me none of these options appears to be proper in terms of security.

Also: There are some functionalities of zabbix that don’t  work when I have PHP FPM in the server, but they do work well when I change it for PHP 5… so it seems to be that I need to do some special configurations to make Zabbix and PHP FPM work together??… what would these configurations be??

Is it recommendable to have Zabbix and PHP FPM working together in the first place?? (I do it because it suppose to increase performance).

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: @StephenKing This isn't StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix performs web requests of web monitoring from Zabbix server (or Zabbix proxy) by default. So yes, it's possible and recommendable to have Zabbix working on a server different from the one that contains tha web-app to be monitored. See doc https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/web_monitoring for more information.

Zabbix web UI is standard web app. It's up to you how do you configure your web server, but zabbix web UI can be accessible via https or on www.domain.com. It's only about web server configuration.

Also PHP-FPM is only about configuration. For example Docker image https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-community-docker is based on PHP-FPM.

Comment: Thank's for replying Jan, useful info for someone who just jumped into zabbix, regards :)